# Remove only some commas from a string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

If I gave you a string as such:

[image: Image of text]

If you look closely in the text there are commas in places like:

```
>,
.,
here, try
```

The first two are common and need to be removed, the last one is normal and should stay in. Most people would suggest:

```
replace(/,/g, '')
```

How ever the issue is that will remove all commas.  Right now its safe to assume that any comma after a closing bracket or  a period can be removed. How ever any other comma should stay in.

Any help on this would be appreciated I don't know if regex is appropriate or if there is a underscore way of doing this or what.

Comment: try a regex where if the comma is preceded by a character that's not a-zA-Z then remove

Comment: Perhaps, [`.replace(/\B,\B/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ3cO3/2) can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing all commas with an empty string, replace all `>,` with `>` and all `.,` with `.`.

`replace(/>,/g, '>')` then `replace(/\.,/g, '.')`

Comment: Issue with the second replace, it turns any comma into a `.` The first one works as desired.

Comment: Woops, `.` matches any character. You need to use `\.` to match only the `.` character. I've updated the answer.